# How to use this keyword inside eval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, this, eval

Having this:

```
const person = {
  name: "James Smith",
  hello: function (x) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + x);
  }
}

function newContext() {
  this.name = "Someone else";
  const code = "(function(){person.hello}).bind(this);"
  eval(code);
}

newContext();
```

There is not output. But don't know why

Comment: Why use `eval` at all?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the function here:

```
(function(){person.hello}).bind(this);
```

is

```
(function(){
  person.hello
}).bind(this);
```

where `person.hello` is just an unused expression. You need `person.hello` (not wrapped in a function) to be on the left-hand side, and you also need to actually call it, with `()` afterwards - or by using `.call`. You also might want to pass an argument (the `x`).

```js
const person = {
  name: "James Smith",
  hello: function (x) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + x);
  }
}

function newContext() {
  this.name = "Someone else";
  const code = "person.hello.call(this, 'xx');"
  eval(code);
}

newContext();
```

```js
const person = {
  name: "James Smith",
  hello: function (x) {
    console.log(this.name + " says hello " + x);
  }
}

function newContext() {
  this.name = "Someone else";
  const code = "person.hello.bind(this)('xx');"
  eval(code);
}

newContext();
```